# If the hinduism is correct religion then why hindus are not improving their lives?

Tags: gods, karma

We know that God is responsible for this world and is driving this world.

If the Hindus are following the correct path which leads to connect with God and order him to get what they want, then why the Hindus are not able to control God to make their lives better?

I heard that God will listen to sages and will do whatever they wish. I know the Sages work for the benefit of universe so whatever they ask that will benefit us all.

Now my question is if the Hinduism is correct religion of all religions then why our Hindus are facing problems mentally, phisically, financially etc?

We did good things in past lives so we luckily born in Hindu religion, so we would have definitely done good things in previous lives, then why are these problems to Hindus? Why Hindus are not able to ask and get from their God what they want?

If its a matter of ability and we are not that capable to know the god, then what is the use of following religion if atleast one in 130 crore people also can not even reach a single inch near to god?

Every one of these 130 crore people follow whatever already existing in vedas, they did not identify anything newly ( even the swamijis like Ramana Maharshi and Chandrashekarendra Saraswati swamiji etc.), then what is the use? According to me, they ( those swamijis) are also not not near to god but their knowledge is more than all of us about god.

Swamijis might have caused rains, they might have removed wars among countries but all their actions came from vedas ( existing knowledge) only, then what is the evidence that they actually experienced God? Both following vedas and experiencing god are different, so I am asking about experiencing god.

If a person studied more about god does not mean that they experienced God. Other religion people also might gained vedas knowledge and they can also do whatever suggested by vedas, then that does not mean that they are near to attain the god.

Example, science says to grow trees because that will benefit atmosphere. so that does not mean that science is leading us to god. Similarly vedas also.

Comment: Great question, either everyone is useless, or the religion is false, those are the only two possibilities.

Comment: Hinduism is correct, Hindus aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We did good things in past lives so we luckily born in Hindu religion, so we would have definitely done good things in previous lives, then why are these problems to Hindus? Why Hindus are not able to ask and get from their God what they want?

Karma is not one thing that can be good or bad. You can have good spiritual Karma (and hence are born in India in a Hindu family) and you can have good wealth Karma (and be born in USA in a milliionaire's family). Or you can have both and perhaps be born in a millionaires family in India, or maybe in another Loka where there exists a location where both come together. When someone says you have good karma to be born in India, it's solely referring to the religious/spiritual aspect, and NOT to wealth, or comfort, or lack of pollution or family etc as those things are governed by other factors.

Just because you're born in India, doesn't mean you won't have financial, emotional or mental troubles, you definitely will have them. If you were destined not to have them, then you would've been born in a Loka where those troubles don't exist at all (which is not this one). Or, you would've been born in the circumstance in this Loka itself where they don't exist.

> Now my question is if the Hinduism is correct religion of all religions then why our Hindus are facing problems mentally, phisically, financially etc?

> Why Hindus are not able to ask and get from their God what they want?

> If its a matter of ability and we are not that capable to know the god, then what is the use of following religion if atleast one in 130 crore people also can not even reach a single inch near to god?

Ishvara works within his own system and rarely breaks those rules. What is that system? It is the system of Karma, you get what you deserve. That is functioning properly and contains no issues. For Hindus specifically there's a little cheat code in the system. By interacting with other separate but way more powerful entities (Devas) via the means of Yajna, we can benefit. This is why the Veda is the most important. Not Vedanta, not whatever else. But specifically Purva Mimamsa, or the Samhita and Brahamana, which is the divine, true and core part of the Veda.

How many people do Yajnas? Basically none. That's why there's no production of any benefit in a large scale. When I say Yajnas, I don't mean one random ritual here and there. There's Yajnas to be done EVERYDAY, every full moon, every no moon etc. In a year, you can easily do a thousand, and all of them would've been the minimum that was done a couple thousand years ago. That's all there is to it. Lack of appropriate Karma from past lives (that removes financial/physical/mental troubles) and lack of creating huge positive Karma (by means of Yajnas). If you already are in a bad situation (bad karma in past lives), and aren't doing anything (Yajnas) to get out of that bad situation. Then, you don't really have a right to complain, do you?

Prayers do not work in any highly tangible amount. That is obvious, to anyone with eyes. If you pray for a car, you won't get it. Karma works, and you have a system to create loads of good Karma (Yajna), if you (so called Hindus) do not utilize it, then it's your problem, not of the system and not of Hinduism.

> I heard that God will listen to sages and will do whatever they wish. I know the Sages work for the benefit of universe so whatever they ask that will benefit us all.

That exists under the condition of Tapasyaa (which is Karma as well). Everything works under Karma except very rare situations where Ishvara breaks his own rules. People nowadays do not have enough Tapasyaa to achieve anything of significance, that's all there is to it. How many people do you see doing month long fasts? Or reading a whole purana in 7 days with only the intake of milk (no food or water). These things are relatively basic that can be found in scriptures. No one does any Tapasyaa so the question of utilizing that tapasyaa to create change in the world is non-existent.

> Every one of these 130 crore people follow whatever already existing in vedas, they did not identify anything newly ( even the swamijis like Ramana Maharshi and Chandrashekarendra Saraswati swamiji etc.), then what is the use? According to me, they ( those swamijis) are also not not near to god but their knowledge is more than all of us about god.

Being 'closer to god' is unrelated to Tapasyaa (which can bring about seemingly miraculous changes), Knowledge of god is also mostly unrelated to being closer. But, without knowledge, you won't get there at all. Having the map to Kaashi doesn't mean you will get to Kaashi, but without the map, you definitely won't get there. Also, those people definitely are 'close' or rather, one, with 'god' or rather, Brahman.

Do not confuse the Upanishat portion of the Veda with the Brahmana/Samhita. The upanishats allow you to get knowledge about Brahman, the actual Veda is all about Yajnas. Following the prior doesn't actually produce any material benefit whatsoever.

Comment: Do you mean Yajnas only help to gain good karma? If you wont help others is also fine?

Comment: @user2225190 Helping people, following Dharma and other things also create good Karma. But, Yajnas create a HUGE amount of Good Karma. You're basically trading what the Devas want (offerings via Yajna) with what you want (rain/children/food/wealth/svarga/fame etc).

Clearly, the karma that is borrowed from Devas will be hundreds if not thousands of times of more value than whatever little you can muster up in your whole life. That doesn't mean that other things don't produce good/bad karma, they do. It's just that Yajna produces a HUGE amount of good Karma.

Comment: If whatever you are saying is correct, then why that good karma wont work immediately? if a person's good karma crossed bad karma in this life, will he escape his bad fate immediately in this life only?

Comment: @user2225190 No he won't, because Karma comes in packages. The package is known as Prarabdha ('begun and propelled'). The package lasts one lifetime. Just as, no matter how much good Karma you do, you cannot become a Yaksha (without dying), in the same way, no matter how much good Karma you do, you cannot get rid of the bad Karma in your fate that has already been propelled and begun (without dying). Think of it like a monthly check. If you do Yajnas, next month your check will be £10,000 instead of what it is now £100, but you still have to wait till next month and make do with 100 for now.

Comment: @user2225190 Some portions of Yajna Phala act immediately though. For example, the Yajna relating to Krimi Naashana Suktam, it immediately destroys harmful bacteria/viruses/fungi in the sorroundings. Or Yajnas for rain etc. But, the majority of the result of Yajnas occurs in the next life.

Comment: Again conditions apply but we dont know what conditions those are. because everyone who do that Suktam cannot destroy those harmful viruses. If a person is bitten by snake and does that Suktam then he wont be cured right?

Comment: Well, naturally conditions will apply... the condition about what the Suktam is for. Ashvamedha Yajna Mantras won't give you happiness in your family simply because that's not the range of those mantras (and related rituals,. Krimi refers to any small creature that resides within the body. It won't have any effect in snake bites, or your hand being chopped off, or you being eaten by a tiger. And, everyone who does utilize the Suktam and relevant Yajna will be cured, unless the Karma to be ill is very high, in which case you can do the Yajna multiple times. There's no other condition. It works.

Comment: @user2225190 mantras and rituals are purposed to cultivate good spiritual karma alone I believe?

Comment: @Haridasa Not really, the majority of Mantras and Rituals are for material benefit, although, some do take the route of causing change in the personality (which can be considered to be spiritual) to achieve said benefit.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar good to see you back :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modern phone with many potential uses and you don't know how to use it, does that make this phone a bad device? So how to apply something for your betterment needs proper knowledge and understanding. Same is true for Hinduism.

Answer (score 1):

**Now my question is if the Hinduism is correct religion of all religions then why our Hindus are facing problems mentally, physically, financially etc?**

Suffering is part of worldly life. No one born in the Earth plane whether they are Hindus or non-Hindus can escape suffering.

> **Contact of the senses with their objects generates cold and heat,
> pleasure and pain. They come and go, being impermanent. Bear with them
> patiently,** O scion of the Bharata race!

**Gita 2.14**

> O leader of men! That enlightened one who is unperturbed alike in
> pleasure and pain, whom these do not distress – he indeed is worthy of
> immortality.

**Gita 2.15**

**The Lord does not normally interfere in the working of the universe** although it is run by His power.

> At the end of a cosmic cycle, O son of Kunti! All beings resolve into
> Nature (Prakrti), which is My own, and at the beginning of a new one
> (after the period of dissolution or Pralaya is over), I bring them out
> again.

**Gita 9.7**

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
> again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
> owing to Nature’s sway over them.

**Gita 9.8**

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, **because I remain detached
> like one unconcerned in their midst.**

**Gita 9.9**

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
> of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
> revolve.

**Gita 9.10**

**What can you do to permanently escape from suffering?**

**Suffering in Life – Need for Moksha**

> "That Ocean, so terrible has sorrow for its waters. Anxiety and grief
> constitute its deep lakes. Disease and Death are its gigantic
> alligators. The great fears that strike the heart at every step are
> its huge snakes. The deeds inspired by Tamas are its tortoises. Those
> inspired by Rajas are its fishes. Wisdom constitutes the raft for
> crossing it. The affections entertained for objects of the senses are
> its mire. Decrepitude constitutes its region of grief and trouble.
> Knowledge..is its island. Acts constitute its great depth. Truth is
> its shores. Pious observances constitute the verdant weeds floating on
> its bosom. Envy constitutes its rapid and mighty current. The diverse
> sentiments of the heart constitute its mines. The diverse kinds of
> gratification are its valuable gems. Grief and fever are its winds.
> Misery and thirst are its mighty eddies. Painful and fatal diseases
> are its huge elephants. The assemblages of bones are its flight of
> steps and phlegm is its froth. Gifts are its pearl-banks. The lakes of
> blood are its corals. Loud laughter constitutes its roars. Diverse
> sciences are its impassibility. Tears are its brine. Renunciation of
> company constitutes the high refuge (of those that seek to cross it).
> Children and spouses are its unnumbered leeches. Friends and kinsmen
> are the cities and towns on its shores. Abstention from injury and
> Truth are its boundary line. Death is its storm-wave. The knowledge of
> Vedanta is its island (capable of affording refuge to those that are
> tossed upon its waters). Acts of compassion towards all creatures
> constitute its life-buoys, and **Emancipation is the priceless commodity**
> offered to those voyaging on the waters in search of merchandise."

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCIII**

Only people who attain moksha will escape suffering.

Answer (score 1):

> *Now my question is if the Hinduism is correct religion of all religions then why our Hindus are facing problems mentally, phisically, financially etc?*

Lord Krishna says this in [Srimad Bhagavatam 10.88](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128969.html)

> 8. I gradually relieve a person of his wealth on whom I wish to bestow my grace. Then his own relatives, finding him penniless and hard-pressed with adversity and sorrow- stricken, forsake him (of their own accord).

> 9. When (he finds that) all his efforts with the desire of acquiring wealth have been futile, he becomes despondent and forms friendship with persons who are devoted to me. Then only I shower my grace on him.

> 10. My grace is the revelation of myself i.e. of Brahman. It is too subtle (to be comprehensible), Pure consciousness and infinite Reality (existence).